# Why can I not use string interpolation for classNames in React?

Tags: reactjs, string

Here's my component:

```
export interface ButtonProps {
  classes?: string[];
}

const Button: FC<ButtonProps> = (props) => {
  const classes = props.classes || [];
  return (
    <button className={`button ${...classes}`}>
      {children}
    </button>
  )
};

export default Button;
```

I'm getting an error - "property classes does not exist...".

It would be great if someone could explain to me why the above code doesn't work.

Many thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the error message? The end seems to be truncated for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that `classes` is an array of strings, not an object, so spreading it into a template literal doesn't make sense. Join by whitespace instead:

```
<button className={`button ${classes.join(' ')}`}>
```

Spread can only be used in:

- argument lists: `fn(...args)`
- array literals: `[...items]`
- object literals: `{ ...props }`

But it can't be used wherever a generic expression is expected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this - since it's an array of strings, can I not use it as though I were spreading an array literal?

Comment: See the last part of my answer - since the inside of a template literal is where a generic expression is expected, and isn't the inside of an argument list, array literal, or object literal, you can't spread inside it. It's not the element *being spread* causing the (immediate) issue, but the location where it's being spread *into*.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use **[clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx)**

```
const { foo, bar, baz } = classes
const style = clsx(foo, bar, baz)

<button className={`button ${style}`}>
```

you can also use as condition

```
const style = clsx({
    [classes.root] : true, //always apply
    [classes.open] : open //only when open === true
})
```